# Change query in URL with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, url

I am needing to update the query part (page_index=) of a URL. I have tried a couple ways shown below but am hitting a wall. I am new to python and looking for guidance. The page index ranges from 0 - 511 (adds new daily) and I need to update the url to loop through all of the indexes. The index will always start at 0.

```
import urlparse

url = 'https://api.appannie.com/v1.2/apps/ios/app/331177714/reviews?
start_date=2016-1-01&end_date=2017-8-26&page_index=0&countries=US'
parts = urlparse.urlparse(url)
parts = parts._replace(query = page_index [2])
parts.geturl()
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-066332f37bb3> in <module>()
  3 url = 'https://api.appannie.com/v1.2/apps/ios/app/331177714/reviews?start_date=2016-1-01&end_date=2017-8-26&page_index=0&countries=US'
  4 parts = urlparse.urlparse(url)
----> 5 parts = parts._replace(query = page_index [2])
  6 parts.geturl()
  7
TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pull out the `query` component of the results of urlparse() and modify it, then reconstruct a new URL, as follows:

```
pr = urlparse.urlparse(url)
parts = pr.query.split('&')
parts[2] = 'page_index=2'
new_url = urlparse.urlunparse([pr.scheme, pr.netloc, pr.path, pr.params, "&".join(parts), pr.fragment])
```

To iterate this through all of your page numbers, loop over the last two lines for whatever range of page numbers you need.

Comment: for your last comment regarding looping over the last two lines. Would I just use a for statement to accomplish this for i in parts(0,500,1):
  print(i)

Comment: Or just `for pg_no in range (500):` if your page numbers start at zero, or `for pg_no in range(1,500)` if they start at 1.

Comment: Hopefully you can tell me what I am doing wrong one last time. have been googling for hours. Below is what I have but am getting error when i .join(pg_no) or just pg_no. Any suggestions? Or am I completely off?  

parts[2] = 'page_index=0'
for pg_no in range (500):
    new_url = urlparse.urlunparse([pr.scheme, pr.netloc, pr.path, pr.params, "&".join(parts), "&".join(pg_no), pr.fragment])

Comment: Modify the 3rd line in the answer to be `parts[2] = 'page_index=%s' % pg_no`

Comment: that is where I thought I needed to modify the code. Thank you for all the help. I appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way, just modify the url directly:

```
base_url = "https://api.appannie.com/v1.2/apps/ios/app/331177714/reviews?start_date=2016-1-01&end_date=2017-8-26&page_index={}&countries=US"

for pi in range(512):
    this_url = base_url.format(pi)
    # now get it
```

A slightly more complicated, but more easily customized, way - passing the parameters as a dict:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.appannie.com/v1.2/apps/ios/app/331177714/reviews"
params = {
    "start_date": "2016-1-01",
    "end_date"  : "2017-8-26"
    "countries" : "US"
}

for pi in range(512):
    params["page_index"] = pi
    res = requests.get(url, params)
    if res.ok:
        html = res.text
```